# Why does my CORS request fail with http 401 error

Tags: apache, http, cors, authorization

I'm using the Fetch API in Javascript to fetch an image from a cross-origin apache server (which I control) but I'm getting the following errors:

SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'http://origin.com' did not find 'http://origin.com' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for cross-origin  resource cross-origin.com/….jpg

HTTP401: DENIED - The requested resource requires user authentication.
(Fetch)GET cross-origin.com/….jpg

Below is the javascript which creates the request object to fetch the jpg:

```
var authb64 = btoa(\'' . $xrefrec['ftp_username'] . ':' .                                   $xrefrec['ftp_password'] . '\');
const request = new Request(document.getElementById(thm.photo_id).href,{
                                \'Access-Control-Request-Headers\': \'Authorization\',
                                \'Options\': \'* HTTP/1.1\',
                                \'Authorization\': \'Basic \' + authb64,
                                \'Origin\': \'http://origin.com\',
                                \'Credentials\': \'include\',
                                \'Cache\': \'no-cache\',
                                \'Mode\': \'cors\',
                                \'Method\': \'GET\'
                            });
```

The code creates an anchor tag, passes the request to fetch(), then awaits the Promise to resolve.

On the server, I've setup a .htaccess file in the directory where the images reside, as follows:

```
AuthName "Client Only"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider dbm
AuthDBMUserFile "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-7.3.11-0/apps/.../conf/.htdbm-users"
Require user (valid user id)
RewriteRule ^/(clientgalleries).*$/ $1 
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header set Cache-Control no-cache
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
Header set WWW-Authenticate: Basic
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://origin.com"
```

Comment: If anyone can help me resolve this, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you're trying to make a CORS request from an unknown domain (you haven't shared it - thats ok) to origin.com. Is this correct?

The `Origin` header cannot be changed by your JavaScript code. For example if you have javascript from `A.com` requesting the image from `B.com`, then `B.com` must allow `A.com` in its `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: No, I'm making a cors request from origin.com to cross-origin.com.

Comment: I should add that the call to fetch() throws an exception resulting in the 401 error.

Comment: Then invert the domains; cross-origin.com must respond with the appropriate Origin whitelist in its CORS preflight response.

Comment: A 401 error suggests that this is not CORS since CORS would be a browser error not permitting you to make the CORS request.

Comment: I probably didn't make that very clear, but it is the cross-origin server that responds with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header as per the last line in .htaccess above.

Comment: Another way of asking this question is, "Why does fetch() crash with an exception when the documentation clearly states that it will handle http errors gracefully?